# Is there something like SQLselect from MapInfo in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql, select

I am a user of MapInfo that will need to adapt increasingly to QGIS.

Is there something like "SQL select" in MapInfo which allows me to easily query between two tables or spatial queries?

MapInfo SQL Window allows you to link easily and efficiently the data in two tables.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question. Can you provide screenshots and some more description for those not familiar with MapInfo?

Comment: Each thread on gis.stackexchange should contain only one question and its answers. This way it's easier for search engines to point people to the correct pages. I see now that you have two completely independent questions. I'll remove the second one. Please repost it in a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

1.8 added DB Manager to the default install, this lets you make connections to spatial databases and create layers from spatial queries.  Your data will have to reside in an actual database such as Postgres/PostGIS or SQLite/Spatialite.

Answer (score 0):

Under vector-->Miscellaneous there is the Execute SQL tool which does this.

It's not as polished as in MapInfo as it doesn't auto populate the fields or assist with the query structure but it works as needed.

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisexecutesql